# Is the achievements dialog broken again?

Tags: bug, status-completed, achievements-dialog

I just earned my first +10 for the day but the achievements dialog didn't seem to display it.

> [image: Image 1]
>
> Where's **'Today'**?

The upvote is shown in the /reputation page.

> [image: Image 2]

### Update

Achievements dialog displayed recent reputation changes at UTC12:40 after a delay of around 40 min. New achievements are still not displayed.

Comment: Yes, broken. Definitely.

Comment: Today is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrsaj.png).

Comment: No. It is [working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TRnu.png). I received rep for less than 1 hour post too.

Comment: It's just broken recently, I didn't receive any notification for the 2 upvotes on this post too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman is the question about SO reputation?

Comment: @Arulkumar Something can break in an hour.

Comment: @Panda where you have 15410 reputation??

Comment: @PatrickHofman in this case it should be on SO meta, I think.

Comment: You think, or you are sure? @alexolut

Comment: @alexolut Seems to be **global** for me, I didn't receive any notification for the upvote on **this** post too

Comment: Doesn't look like SO, OP got less reputation there. /cc @Patrick

Comment: @ShadowWizard Lol, magic. The site's not shown in my profile :-)

Comment: Well, because you Hide it...

Comment: Badges still come through, just rep isn't.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ... like (beta) politics.

Comment: I just received +5 from this post, so it's fixed? (I think)

Comment: You think, or you are sure? // cc @PatrickHofman :)

Comment: Momentarily it was fixed. Events are still not coming through (or there is a delay).

Comment: @PatrickHofman Apparently, there's a huge delay of about 30min so it doesn't seem to be completely fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were some changes to a serialized message format that were not deployed to all affected sites — meaning that the format was wrong on some of them.

This caused the queue to choke on them and fill up instead of clearing out. I have manually cleared those out and ensured the change was propagated to all sites using this message format.

Sorry for the disruption.